# how to use break in for loop of swig template node js?

Tags: swig-template

Hello i am trying to stop my loop when it reaches to half of the total length.

just like using break it is not happening.

```
  {% if page.member && page.member.length > 0 %}
   {% for member in page.member %}
     {{ member }}
     {% if loop.index0 == ((page.member.length/2)-1) %}
       {% set count = loop.index %}
        {% break %}
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

please look into it.
Thanking you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `{% break %}` tag in Swig templates.

You don't need the break tag:

```
{% if page.member && page.member.length > 0 %}
 {% set count = false %}
 {% for member in page.member %}
   {% if not count %}
     {{ member }}
     {% if loop.index0 == ((page.member.length/2)-1) %}
       {% set count = loop.index %}
     {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```